# Embedding Perl-only modules along with embedded Perl interpreter

Tags: perl, module, embed

I followed https://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed and succeeded in building an `interp` binary. When I use `static_ext`, the output directory has `*.pm` files installed into a prefix directory.

How can I add custom simple `*.pm` modules such as [TLUtils.pm](https://github.com/TeX-Live/installer/tree/master/tlpkg/TeXLive) without having to unpack the module files into a temporary directory? Basically, as an example I'd like to embed https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl and https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/updmap.pl that depend on TLUtils. A more complex goal may be packaging [biber](https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/338) without using PAR.

Can I somehow import this modules into an interpreter given `*.pm`'s source code?

On the virtual file system side, does anyone have an example of rolling a primitive read-only virtual file system (e.g. by overriding `lstat`, `open`, `read`) for importing packages from memory?

I realize that PAR solves this problem, but I'm wondering if there are simple crutches that I could use without taking a dependency on PAR.

Thank you!

UPD:

```sh
mkdir -p source build/native/perl
wget -nc https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.30.0.tar.gz -P source
tar -xf source/*.tar.gz --strip-components=1 --directory=build/native/perl
cd build/native/perl
bash ./Configure -sde -Dprefix=$PWD/../prefix -Aldflags=-lm -Accflags=-lm -Dstatic_ext="IO Fcntl"
make miniperl generate_uudmap
make perl
make install

../prefix/bin/perl5.30.0 -e 'print 123; use Fcntl; print 456;'
# prints 123456

../prefix/bin/perl5.30.0 -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts
# -Wl,-E  -lm -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib /home/runner/work/buildbiber/buildbiber/build/native/perl/../prefix/lib/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.a /home/runner/work/buildbiber/buildbiber/build/native/perl/../prefix/lib/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/auto/IO/IO.a -L/home/runner/work/buildbiber/buildbiber/build/native/perl/../prefix/lib/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/CORE -lperl -lpthread -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc           -lm -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector-strong -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -I/home/runner/work/buildbiber/buildbiber/build/native/perl/../prefix/lib/5.30.0/x86_64-linux/CORE

cc -o emperl ../../../emperl.c `../prefix/bin/perl5.30.0 -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts -e ldopts`
./emperl -e 'print 123; use Fcntl; print 456;'
# prints Can't load module Fcntl, dynamic loading not available in this perl.
#  (You may need to build a new perl executable which either supports
#  dynamic loading or has the Fcntl module statically linked into it.)
# at -e line 1.
# Compilation failed in require at -e line 1.

# This is an extremely strange error because Fcntl is indeed built and linked statically as evidenced by the linking flags above

echo '{' > fmtutil_.pl
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeX-Live/installer/master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm >> fmtutil_.pl
echo '}' >> fmtutil_.pl
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl >> fmtutil_.pl

./emperl fmtutil_.pl --help
# also fails with Fcntl problem
```

Comment: *"When I use static_ext ..."* What is `static_ext` ? I could not find it mentioned in the [INSTALL](https://metacpan.org/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.34.0/view/INSTALL) document.

Comment: It is a Perl's ./Configure switch allowing for compiling/linking extensions statically

Comment: Ok :) strange that it is not mentioned in the `INSTALL` document then. Can you give an example of how you use this switch when compiling your `interp` binary?

Comment: I updated my question with full repro (for now this prepends TLUtils.pm to fmtutil.pl)

Comment: Thanks for the update, when I follow your setup and try to run `make miniperl` it fails with `Attempt to free unreferenced scalar: SV 0x55d8764814c8.`. [Here](https://pastebin.com/Wi907sSp) is the complete output log. I am on Ubuntu 21.04.

Comment: My snippet is running on Ubuntu 20.04. Maybe try a more recent Perl 5.35.4? Here is my Github Action with this code: https://github.com/busytex/buildbiber/blob/ec66629/.github/workflows/emperl.yml

Comment: *"Maybe try a more recent Perl 5.35.4?"* Yes it worked with 5.34.0..

Comment: I also created a companion GitHub bug specifically about the Fcntl problem: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/issues/19161

Comment: *"Can't load module Fcntl, dynamic loading not available in this perl"* : Yes I get this message too.. Have you tried to pass an `xs_init()` function pointer to `perl_parse()` as described in [perlembed](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed) ?

Comment: I am not able to make `xs_init()` work. [Here](https://pastebin.com/p3Y1sEH0) is my output..

Comment: Have you tried the approach described under section *"Static Linking of a new Perl binary"* in the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/ExtUtils::MakeMaker#Static-Linking-of-a-new-Perl-Binary) for `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` ?

Comment: I'll try, but is's fishy, because the `perl5.35.4` binary works fine, it's the custom one that's failing. The only difference seems in function `main`, maybe custom perl instance tries to do dynamic loading even if everything is already linked statically.

Comment: Maybe `mkbundle` file from http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/App-Staticperl.html could be of help, because it also contains a `main` function for a custom statically-linked interpreter...

Comment: Probably you're right about `xs_init`, need to look into it...

Comment: *"I am not able to make xs_init() work"* : Sorry I forgot to also change `emperl.c`, see my answer below. It seems to work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The first issue:

> Can't load module Fcntl, dynamic loading not available in this perl.

According to [perlembed](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlembed) you need to insert some XS glue code into your embedded interpreter `emperl.c`:

```
#include <EXTERN.h>               /* from the Perl distribution     */
#include <perl.h>                 /* from the Perl distribution     */
static PerlInterpreter *my_perl;  /***    The Perl interpreter    ***/
EXTERN_C void xs_init (pTHX);

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
       PERL_SYS_INIT3(&argc,&argv,&env);
       my_perl = perl_alloc();
       perl_construct(my_perl);
       PL_exit_flags |= PERL_EXIT_DESTRUCT_END;
       perl_parse(my_perl, xs_init, argc, argv, (char **)NULL);
       perl_run(my_perl);
       perl_destruct(my_perl);
       perl_free(my_perl);
       PERL_SYS_TERM();
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Note that `perl_parse()` is now run with a pointer to an `xs_init` subroutine as second argument. The `xs_init()` function can be generated and compiled into the `emperl` binary using these commands:

```
PERL=build/native/prefix/bin/perl5.34.0
$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e xsinit -- -o perlxsi.c
cc -c perlxsi.c `$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts`
cc -c emperl.c `$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts`
cc -o emperl perlxsi.o emperl.o `$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts`
```

If I now test the embedded binary like you did it seems to work fine:

```
$ ./emperl -e 'print 123; use Fcntl; print 456;'
123456
```

#### The second issue:

> How can I add custom simple `*.pm` modules such as `TLUtils.pm` without having to unpack the module files into a temporary directory?

According to the [INSTALL](https://metacpan.org/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.34.0/view/INSTALL#Extensions) document:

> If you unpack any additional extensions in the `ext/` directory before running `Configure`, then `Configure` will offer to build those additional extensions as well.

I tried this with a simple XS module [`Sort::Key`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key) like this (here I use `Configure` option `-Uusedl` to force `perl` to be compiled completely statically):

```
mkdir -p source build/native/perl
wget -nc https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.34.0.tar.gz -P source
tar -xf source/*.tar.gz --strip-components=1 --directory=build/native/perl
cd build/native/perl
cd ext
wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/S/SA/SALVA/Sort-Key-1.33.tar.gz
mkdir -p Sort-Key
tar -xf Sort-Key-1.33.tar.gz --strip-components=1 --directory=Sort-Key
cd ..
sh ./Configure -sde -Dman1dir=none -Dman3dir=none -Dprefix=$PWD/../prefix -Uusedl
make
make install
```

Then embedded this `perl` using the `emperl.c` code as before:

```
PERL=build/native/prefix/bin/perl5.34.0
$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e xsinit -- -o perlxsi.c
# Note: for some reason you need to comment out the two lines with 
#   Devel::PPPort from perlxsi.c in order to compile it..
perl -i -ne 'print if !/PPPort/' perlxsi.c
cc -c perlxsi.c `$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts`
cc -c emperl.c `$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e ccopts`
cc -o emperl perlxsi.o emperl.o `$PERL -MExtUtils::Embed -e ldopts`
```

Then tested the embedded interpreter with the `Sort::Key` module:

```
$ ./emperl -e 'print 123; use Sort::Key; print 456'
123456
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the correct answer but to the intermediate problem. The question is back to the original one. How to embed multiple module files? Or how to concatenate them properly? Is there a specific file order to follow?

For `fmtutil.pl`, it's just a few module dependencies, so I can figure them out manually, but for Biber it's many more

Comment: *"Is there a specific file order to follow?"* : Are you asking how to determine all dependencies of a script? I think for complex scripts it can be difficult. You may have to use trial and error, but I think you can get many by using a tool like [Module::ScanDeps](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::ScanDeps). Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm asking about how to package the dependent package directory tree to be available to the embedded interpreter without unpacking the `*.pm` files on disk. Preferably via just calling some functions on the embedded interpreter instance, alternatively an example of a primitive file system call overrides.

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood your question. So you do not want to embed the modules in the `perl` when building `perl`, but download the module files later and use them from an embedded perl binary? Though I am not sure I understand why you would do that?

Comment: I'd like to have an embedded Perl that runs a script that depends on some Perl modules. I'd like to make these dependencies available without unpacking them to the disk.

Comment: So you are not able to compile/build your own perl first? Like I showed in my answer above? Am I correct in assuming that you are going to use a perl that is preinstalled on the system, such that you cannot modify it?

Comment: I am able to build my own Perl, just like you suggested. I'd like to use my embedded Perl instance in order to run a script that depends on `*.pm` files. I'd like to avoid having these `*.pm` files on disk.

Comment: In my example, I showed how you can embed the `.pm` files (modules) when you compile perl. It is not clear to me why you would not do this?

Comment: Sorry! I must not have seen the version of your example with SortKey. Does it require any files on disk? I'll try it and if it works, I'll definitely mark your answer as the correct one!

Comment: *"Does it require any files on disk?"* When you build perl you need files on disk of course, you need to download tar ball https://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.34.0.tar.gz and unpack it, and similarly with the modules you want to include inside the `ext` directory. But afterwards, when using the embedded binary no additional files are needed as far as I can see

Comment: I'm trying `mkdir ext/TeXLive; wget -P ext/TeXLive https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeX-Live/installer/master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLConfig.pm https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeX-Live/installer/master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm`, but during build getting error `For TeXLive tried TeXLive.pm TeXLive.pm lib/TeXLive.pm in ext/TeXLive but can't find source at make_ext.pl line 385.`

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at this later

Comment: Thank you! Basically then I'd like to at least run `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl; ./emperl fmtutil.pl --help`. And at the best - to also embed this script somehow along with the `TeXLive` module and be able to call it from C.

Comment: I think Sort-Key has some extra metadata files that make it recognizable as proper "extension", and `TeXLive/*.pm` files somehow do not correspond to an "extension"

Comment: "*...has some extra metadata files that make it recognizable as proper "extension".."* : Yes it has a [Makefile.PL](http://blogs.perl.org/users/neilb/2017/04/an-introduction-to-distribution-metadata.html) so it can be installed by running `perl Makefile.PL; make; make install`. I think you can generate a `Makefile.PL` manually, it should be quite simple since the modules are pure Perl modules

Comment: Alternatively, you may try the approach described in the [INSTALL](https://metacpan.org/release/XSAWYERX/perl-5.34.0/view/INSTALL#Installation-Directories) document under the sections *"Directories for site-specific add-on files"*, and *"Directories for vendor-supplied add-on files"*. You should be able to simply copy the module files here since they are pure Perl modules and thus does not need any compilation

Comment: I think I would have tried the approach described under the section *"Directories for site-specific add-on files"*

Comment: Well, I'd like them to embed in my C binary and to avoid extra files on disk - that's why I'm doing this whole thing. I'll see about `Makefile.PL`

Comment: Maybe it's possible to specify these pure Perl modules with some other Configure switch other than `static_ext`...

Comment: *"Well, I'd like them to embed in my C binary and to avoid extra files on disk"* I don't think you can embed pure Perl modules in the binary. For example, the pure Perl core modules are always represented as files on disk. For example after running `sh ./Configure -sde -Dprefix=$PWD/../prefix -Uusedl; make; make install` the install directory will contain  316 directories and 1687 files (in my case). You cannot embed all of those files. Please clarify why you do not want those files on disk

Comment: I'd like to dsitribute a single file and to not extract anything on the disk, so that the user doesn't deal with Perl artifacts in any way at all. I know this is possible with `staticperl` or `PAR`, but I don't want to take a dependency on them and  would like to have the embedding pipeline as basic as possible.

Comment: I was not aware of `staticperl`.. then I would look at the source of [staticperl](https://metacpan.org/pod/staticperl) and try to understand how it is done

Comment: Do you know where is Python's `*.pm` module loading code located in https://github.com/perl/perl5? I'd like to see what file system functions it uses...

Comment: I suppose you mean Perl, not Python? Have a look at the file `pp_ctl.c`, at [line 3859](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/pp_ctl.c#L3859) there is a function `S_require_file()`

Comment: It seems that `S_doopen_pm` is the relevant function used for opening `*.pm` files: https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/pp_ctl.c#L3732, and then it goes into `S_check_type_and_open` at https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/f79e2ff95fbb22eaf18e130c7cba8a9d40be3d75/pp_ctl.c#L3658

Comment: Then it all boils down to https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/blead/iperlsys.h which defines `PerlLIO_open`, `PerlLIO_lstat` and `PerlLIO_read`. Can't find for now where the underlying `PL_LIO` variable gets initialized

Comment: Basically, a question is: how is it possible to override the Perl's IO-related functions or callbacks?