# How to define multiple Perl packages in one file that are inter-dependent

Tags: perl, package

I've tried following some other examples and have something like:

```perl
{
    package Foo::Bar;
}
{
    package Foo::Baz;

    use Foo::Bar;
}

use Foo::Baz;
# some more code 

# Fails with: Can't locate Foo/Bar.pm in @INC
```

My real-world example is I'd like to bundle/concat https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/trunk/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl along with its dependencies https://github.com/TeX-Live/installer/blob/master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLConfig.pm and https://github.com/TeX-Live/installer/blob/master/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm into a single file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Perl doesn't know the module is already loaded because you haven't faithfully replicated the loading process. Specifically, you didn't modify `%INC`.

You could also have problems from not loading the module at compile-time. This could be achieved using a `BEGIN` block.

To inline a module, add the following to the start of your script:

```perl
BEGIN {
   # Insert module here.

   $INC{ ( __PACKAGE__ =~ s{::}{/}rg ) . ".pm" } = 1;
}
```

So if you had

```perl
# script.pl
use strict;
use Foo::Baz;
# ...
```

```perl
# Foo/Bar.pm
package Foo::Bar;
use strict;
# ...
1;
```

```perl
# Foo/Baz.pm
package Foo::Baz;
use strict;
use Foo::Bar;
# ...
1;
```

You'd end up with

```perl
BEGIN {
   # Foo/Bar.pm
   package Foo::Bar;
   use strict;
   # ...
   $INC{ ( __PACKAGE__ =~ s{::}{/}rg ) . ".pm" } = 1;
}

BEGIN {
   # Foo/Baz.pm
   package Foo::Baz;
   use strict;
   use Foo::Bar;
   # ...
   $INC{ ( __PACKAGE__ =~ s{::}{/}rg ) . ".pm" } = 1;
}

# script.pl
use strict;
use Foo::Baz;
# ...
```

---

Note the above isn't 100% equivalent to inlining the modules. For example, the equivalent of

```perl
use 5.012;
use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)";
use Some::Module;
```

would actually be

```perl
# Non-lexical effects
BEGIN {
   require 5.012;
   binmode(STDIN,  ":encoding(UTF-8)");
   binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)");
   binmode(STDERR, ":encoding(UTF-8)");
}

BEGIN {
   package Some::Module;
   ...
   $INC{"Some/Module.pm"} = 1;
}

# Lexical effects
use 5.012;
use open ":encoding(UTF-8)";
```

To properly inline a module, it would be better to use an `@INC` hook. Using the files from the first approach, one would end up with

```perl
BEGIN {
   my %modules = (
      "Foo/Bar.pm" => <<'__EOI__',
# Foo/Bar.pm
package Foo::Bar;
use strict;
# ...
1;
__EOI__
      "Foo/Baz.pm" => <<'__EOI__',
# Foo/Baz.pm
package Foo::Baz;
use strict;
use Foo::Bar;
# ...
1;
__EOI__
   );

   unshift @INC, sub {
      my $module = $modules{$_[1]}
         or return;

      return \$module;
   };
}

# script.pl
use strict;
use Foo::Baz;
# ...
```

[App::FatPacker](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) can be used to inline modules this way.

The line numbers in warnings and errors will be the line numbers of the original file. a `#line` directive added to the inlined module would adjust that.

Comment: It worked! But I also had to remove stuff from `__END__` up to a `=cut` at the end of one of `*.pm` modules. If by chance you know of embedding pure Perl modules along with the custom Perl binary (related to this same task), my other related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69405351/embedding-perl-only-modules-along-with-embedded-perl-interpreter/69410271

Comment: Re "*I also had to remove stuff from `__END__`*", Not with the @INC hook approach I mentioned /// Re "*If by chance [...]*",  PAR surely uses the @INC hook I mentioned above.

Comment: You're right! I used the first, simpler (but incomplete) solution you had proposed!

Comment: In the first solution you proposed, is the order of modules important, and in the second it is not important. Correct?

Comment: Yes . . . . . .

Comment: The `@INC` hook method is not reliable in case some embedded perl modules does `unshift` into the beginning of `@INC` some other directory containing a module with an identical name to embbeded ones. Is it possible to somehow force-import all the embedded modules?

Comment: A module should not be touching `@INC`. /// Re "*Is it possible to somehow force-import all the embedded modules?*",  yeah. They're right there in `%modules`.

Comment: Hmm. The thing is that I appended  a script: https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/92c38ad23e396ba3c67728998a7857791d401ea8/texk/texlive/linked_scripts/texlive/fmtutil.pl#L22 which actually modifies the `@INC` and prevented the hook from running correctly. For now I'm just commenting out these lines that touch INC

Comment: That's a script, not a module. you could just put your inlined modules after the changes to @INC.

Comment: This script, besides `@INC`-modification, also consumes the `@INC`-embedded modules, so if I put inlined modules after, they wouldn't get visible. For now my workaround is okay, but it's very fragile...

Comment: Wait, no, prepending to `@INC` shouldn't break the hook. Sure, it means you might grab the file from the disk instead of from the "virtual file system" provided by the hook, but that what the the script always does. It will still fall back to the "virtual file system" if the file isn't found in the prepended path.

Comment: The problem is that it prepends some path which contains another version of the embedded modules, and thus shadows them :)

Comment: Another question is that in the script the are things like `require("mktexlsr.pl")`. Is it possible to also embed such scripts to be `require`'d?

Comment: Yes. __________

Comment: Would you have an advice on how to reliably remove `pod` documentation from the Perl sources? pod documentation currently prevents your proposed amalgamation solution from working reliably :(

Comment: @Vadim Kantorov, As previously mentioned, if you want to automate this process, use App::FatPacker.

Answer (score 2):

You do not `use` packages defined in the same file. They are already compiled and parsed by loading the file.  Example:

```
{
    package Foo::Bar;

    sub bar { print "bar\n" }
}
{
    package Foo::Baz;

    sub baz {
        Foo::Bar::bar();
        print "baz\n"
    }
}

use strict;
use warnings;

Foo::Baz::baz();
```

**Output**:

```
bar
baz
```

The [`use`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use) statement is used to load other files (Perl modules) from `@INC`.

Comment: Is there another way to concat inter-dependent `*.pm` packages into a single file? Thank you!

Comment: See [App:FatPacker](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::FatPacker) for an example

Comment: Thank you! I'll check it. I hope it doesn't unpack temp files onto the disk.

Answer (score 2):

In normal settings, the `use Module` call has two jobs:

1. Find the source file `Module.pm` and parse it like a compile-phase `require` call, and
2. Call the `Module::import` function

By inlining your modules, you don't need to do the first job. The functions and set up code for the module are already defined in the correct namespace.

Calling `import` for the second step may or may not be necessary, or may be necessary several times, depending on what functions can be exported and what namespaces you want to use them in.

```
package Foo::Bar;
use parent 'Exporter';
@Foo::Bar::EXPORT_OK = qw(bar1 bar2);
sub bar1 { 47 }
sub bar2 { 73 }

package Foo::Baz;
@Foo::Baz::EXPORT_OK = "baz1";
use parent 'Exporter';
Foo::Bar->import("bar1");
sub baz1 { return bar1() + 42 }

package main;
Foo::Bar->import("bar2");
Foo::Baz->import("baz1");
sub main2 { return bar2() + baz1() + 19 }
```

Comment: Delayng the import to compile time can bite you.. Also note that pragrams in one of your module will leak into the others.